# Getting WinError 3 or UnicodeDecodeError from os.listdir(path)

Tags: python, path, command-prompt, administrator, network-drive

I realise that this will look like a duplicate question however I have checked all the questions that I could find that seem relevant and none solve my issue.

I generate my variable `myPath` in the most pythonic way I know how using `os.path.join`
I have also tried using strings with `r'path_string'`and even using forward slashes instead however both also give me `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified`

I also tried using `b'path_string'` however this just gave me a different error, so that wasn't helpful either: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 69: invalid start byte`

All of these errors are generated by the same line in my code:
`files = os.listdir(path)`

Before anyone asks I have triple checked the directory path of the shared drive and it does exist and there is access to it.
It would also appear that the issue is arising from running this program from the command prompt as an administrator which does make this more of an academic question.

Full code is below,

```
import os

#myPath = 'z:/Data/App_Projects/Client_Data/Client/Date'
#myPath = b'z:/Data/App_Projects/Client_Data/Client/Date'
myPath = os.path.join("z:", os.sep, "Data", "App_Projects", "Client_Data", "Client", "Date")

files = os.listdir(myPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be coming from the fact that this is a networked drive. Although the user being used is an administrator when using an elevated command prompt the networked drive no longer associated with that session as it is only mapped for the non elevated session.

This was explained in [this](https://superuser.com/a/202840/337396) answer by Alberto Martinez on SuperUser but I think its relevant here as its not neccessarily an obvious cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can still access network drive files using python if you know the network path.

```
network_path = r"\\192.168.0.1" # or \\your_network_name
myPath = os.path.join(network_path, "Data", "App_Projects", "Client_Data", "Client", "Date")
```

Comment: You can still access network drive files without that if you have already mapped it to a drive letter as well, your solution only works if it is an unsecured network drive unless you can pass credentials every time you access it?